# sybase sql: choose records for which sum of values in column XYZ equals some specific value

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, sybase

Using Sybase SQL, I want to find all records fulffilling certain simple requirements (such as DEBITCREDIT == 'D') AND the following requirement:
the sum of the nominal values of these records must equal 300

Specifically, I want to do something like this:

```
select RECORD_ID   ,
       BOOKING_ID
  from RECORDS          
 where SECURITIES_ID       = 'B'   
   and DEBITCREDIT         = 'D'
   and sum(NOMINAL_VALUE)  = 300 -- NOT ALLOWED!
```

The problem is that this is not allowed.
How can I achieve my goal in a way that is allowed and works?

... Here is a screenshot as an example:
[image: Table RECORDS]

In the screenhot the purpose of my select statement would be to select the RECORD_IDs highlighted in yellow, namely RECORD_ID 2 and RECORD_ID 4.
(Please note that NOMINAL_VALUE of RECORD_ID 2 + NOMINAL_VALUE of RECORD_ID 4 = 300.)

Comment: You would need to explain how nominal values work. If you're summing then presumably multiple rows are involved.

Comment: SUM is GROUPINg function, your code has no `GROUP BY` so your query doesn't make sense in the first place, so explain which sum you want

Comment: select RECORD_ID, BOOKING_ID from RECORDS  where SECURITIES_ID = :1
and DEBITCREDIT = :2 group by RECORD_ID, BOOKING_ID having sum(NOMINAL_VALUE)=:3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `sum(NOMINAL_VALUE)=300` refers to ***all rows*** where `SECURITIES_ID='B' and DEBITCREDIT='D'`
- we are *NOT* looking for a *subset* of rows (`SECURITIES_ID='B' and DEBITCREDIT='D'`) where `sum(NOMINAL_VALUE)=300`; for example ...
- if we were looking for `sum(NOMINAL_VALUE)=100` then we would return nothing (ie, we would *not* return `RECORD_ID=2`)

Create/populate a sample table:

```
create table RECORDS
(RECORD_ID      int
,SECURITIES_ID  char(1)
,DEBITCREDIT    char(1)
,NOMINAL_VALUE  int
,BOOKING_ID     int
)
go

insert RECORDS values (1,'A','C',100,10)
insert RECORDS values (2,'B','D',100,20)
insert RECORDS values (3,'B','C',100,30)
insert RECORDS values (4,'B','D',200,40)
insert RECORDS values (5,'C','D', 50,50)
go
```

There are a few ways to slice-n-dice this ...

---

Using a subquery with no explicit join to the parent:

```
select  r.RECORD_ID,
        r.BOOKING_ID
from    RECORDS r
where   r.SECURITIES_ID = 'B'
and     r.DEBITCREDIT   = 'D'
and     300 = (select   sum(r2.NOMINAL_VALUE)
                 from   RECORDS r2
                 where  r2.SECURITIES_ID = 'B'
                 and    r2.DEBITCREDIT   = 'D')
order by 1,2
```

**NOTE:** there's no explicit 'join' criteria so OP needs to be very careful to insure both the parent query and subquery reference the same exact set of rows

This generates:

```
 RECORD_ID   BOOKING_ID
 ----------- -----------
           2          20
           4          40
```

---

Modifying the previous query by *a)* converting the subquery to a derived table and *b)* joining the parent to the derived table via the `SECURITES_ID` and `DEBITCREDIT` columns:

```
select  r.RECORD_ID,
        r.BOOKING_ID
from    RECORDS r
join    (select r2.SECURITIES_ID,
                r2.DEBITCREDIT,
                sum(r2.NOMINAL_VALUE)
         from   RECORDS r2
         where  r2.SECURITIES_ID = 'B'
         and    r2.DEBITCREDIT   = 'D'
         group by r2.SECURITIES_ID,
                  r2.DEBITCREDIT
         having sum(r2.NOMINAL_VALUE) = 300) dt
on      r.SECURITIES_ID = dt.SECURITIES_ID
and     r.DEBITCREDIT   = dt.DEBITCREDIT
order by 1,2
```

This also generates:

```
 RECORD_ID   BOOKING_ID
 ----------- -----------
           2          20
           4          40
```

---

If this is `Sybase ASE` we can make use of its support of non-ANSI compliant SQL with this really fugly query:

```
select  RECORD_ID,
        BOOKING_ID
from    RECORDS
where   SECURITIES_ID = 'B'
and     DEBITCREDIT   = 'D'
group by SECURITIES_ID, 
         DEBITCREDIT
having sum(NOMINAL_VALUE) = 300
order by 1,2
```

**NOTES:**

- the query plan for this is similar to the query plan for the other queries, ie, it requires two accesses of the `RECORDS` table
- while it's tempting to use this 'simpler' non-ANSI compliant SQL query, I'd recommend one of the other queries as they'll be easier to understand (especially for someone who comes across this code at a later date)

This also generates:

```
 RECORD_ID   BOOKING_ID
 ----------- -----------
           2          20
           4          40
```

---

**NOTE:** all queries were run on an `ASE 16.0 SP04 PL04` instance

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the aggregated sum using `HAVING`. For example:

```
select RECORD_ID, BOOKING_ID
from RECORDS
where RECORD_ID in (
  select RECORD_ID
  from RECORDS          
  where SECURITIES_ID = 'B' and DEBITCREDIT = 'D'
  group by RECORD_ID
  having sum(NOMINAL_VALUE) = 300
)
```